# There was an internal error when querying iis 7.0 for profiling

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, visual-studio-2012, profiling

I have a WCF Service that is running too slow.

I wanted to profile it, so I followed the instructions found here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s0xxa1d.aspx

When I try to start up the profiling I get this error:

> There was an internal error when querying IIS 7.0 for profiling. Ensure that you have all of the following Internet Information Services (IIS) and IIS 6 Management Compatibility components installed:
>
> Web Server,
>
> Windows Authentication,
>
> ASP.NET,
>
> IIS Metabase Compatibility,
>
> IIS 6 WMI Compatibility,
>
> IIS 6 Scripting Tools

The service runs just fine normally.  Do I really need to install IIS 6 stuff to get the profiling to work?

Comment: Unfortunately. Yes, you do.

Answer (score 5):

Try enabling them by following these instructions:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397374%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As part of the answer above I had to also install the following Windows Features.

**1. These items**

[image]

**2. And also these**

[image]